# How can I see what objects have not been released by the .NET Runtime/Garbage collection?

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection, out-of-memory

I am stepping in to help debug a service running in production which is regularly throwing `System.OutOfMemoryException`s.  Looking back through the logs, this has been happening a long time, so we can't look at recent changes to see what has caused it.  The service pick jobs off a queue and runs the appropriate process.  There are 10's of different processes and the service processes thousands of jobs per day.  Depending on how busy the users are, the exceptions take 1 to 10 days to start happening.

I'm assuming one (or more) of the processes implemented has a memory leak.  Running a profiler in Production is not going to be possible, and reproducing the problem in a test environment is also proving time-consuming.

The easiest approach would be to add code to the service which dumps a list of objects being held by the process on a regular basis and see which classes are building up over time.

Does anyone know how this could be done?

Comment: if you're not seeing any leaks  under test check your logs to see what errors may be happening in production that are not happening under test.  You should also look to insure whatever way you're testing includes the production workflows with an eye to seeing if there's corner cases you've left out of the test workflows.

Comment: You could make [snapshots with Performance Profiler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/memory-usage-without-debugging2?view=vs-2019) and compare outputs.

Comment: Would you be able to run [PerfView](https://github.com/Microsoft/perfview/blob/master/documentation/Downloading.md) in Production? See [this blog series](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/work-flow-of-diagnosing-memory-performance-issues-part-0/) for how you would use it

Comment: Ah and 'time-consuming' is not really an excuse for daily OOM in production env ;)